# In the US, is cancer medication (for a parent living in South America), tax-deductible?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, california, washington

The cancer medication of my parent costs 10,000 USD a month. I would like to pay for this, but I wouldn't have enough money to live off of myself. I was wondering, would the expense would be tax deductible?

In case state law is important, I have the option to work in California or in Washington state.

Comment: Making it tax deductible only saves you up to 30% depending on your tax bracket - does that make it suddenly affordable for you?

Comment: @DStanley It gives me enough to live off of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deduct the medical expense, you'd need to be able to claim your father as a dependent on your taxes, and then could only deduct the amount in excess of 7.5% of your AGI. Check out [IRS Publication 502 on Medical and Dental Expenses](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p502).

Comment: So the answer is no then? Not while he's living in Chile. I read in this article that I can't claim them as a dependent if he lives in Chile re: (https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/4122475-my-parents-are-not-us-citizens-and-they-live-overseas-i-assist-them-financially-is-this-assistance-tax-deductible-when-i-file-what-proof-do-i-need)